# Is it possible to redirect myshopify admin page or change query from imbedded app in PHP?

Tags: php, shopify, session-cookies, shopify-app, samesite

Any redirect causes a "*.myshopify.com refused to connect." a 302 error,
if called like this:

```
header('Location: ' . $location);
```

or "*.myshopify.com redirected you too many times." a 302 error, with echo:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='" . $location . "';</script>";
```

It says SameSite=Lax prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request.
But trying to change it with:

```
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=whatever; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Yet, still, redirect is not allowed.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee sorry

Comment: Unsure if removing the information entirely is an improvement. Probably at least summarize what was in the image?

Comment: i tried creating a text table, but its too big, it was either removing it, or leaving it as an image, the image wasn't even that important, just an image of all the cookies, and their status, I was not sure if that would help, but I added them just in case, in case they show useful data

Answer (score 0):

Can you write here about $location content ? if your $location data is a same url with currently it will be again infinite. Please enter code

```php
<?php
// .........

die($location);
```

and write here exits result.

Comment: its just redirecting if the page is 

https://dev-ess-teststore.myshopify.com/admin/apps/ess_app/pages/bulk.php
what I was trying to do, was either go to:
https://dev-ess-teststore.myshopify.com/admin/orders
or add query
https://dev-ess-teststore.myshopify.com/admin/apps/ess_app/pages/bulk.php?Ids=111

of course the app is run on xamp localhost

Comment: I thinks , there is a problem with your desire. Because if you using xamp service maybe hosts uncorrectly configured . For fix issue maybe need to you send request from postman. Send request from postman to necessary url and look for headers. I think, you will view redirecting url from header. It is very necessary for fix issue.